# Drawing rectangles using OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, facial-identification

I am trying to draw the faces detected in a video live on it, but I seem to be having troubles getting it to work

```
var haarcascade = new CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/NotMyName/Desktop/haar/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
using (Window window = new Window("capture"))
using (Mat image = new Mat())//Image Buffer
{
    while (true)
    {
        Video.Read(image);
        var gray = image.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.RGB2GRAY);
        OpenCvSharp.Rect[] faces = haarcascade.DetectMultiScale(gray, 1.08, 2, HaarDetectionTypes.ScaleImage, new OpenCvSharp.Size(30,30));
        foreach (Rect i in faces)
        {
            Cv2.Rectangle(image, (faces[i].BottomRight.X, faces[i].BottomRight.Y), (faces[i].TopLeft.X, faces[i].TopLeft.Y), 255, 1);
        }
```

However, the compiler is only spitting errors. Passing the faces array directly to the function also didn't work. The error message is (translated from German).

> Error  CS0029 The Type "OpenCvSharp.Rect" can't be converted to "int"

Comment: Which line triggered that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that correct way should be this:

```
...
foreach (Rect i in faces)
{
    Cv2.Rectangle(image, new Point(i.BottomRight.X, i.BottomRight.Y), new Point(i.TopLeft.X, i.TopLeft.Y), 255, 1);
}
....
```

The local variable `i` inside the foreach reference to current `Rect`.

`Cv2.Rectangle` method accepts `OpenCvSharp.Point`.

Comment: That was the one, however, it demanded that I specify it as an OpenCvSharp.Point, as you pointed out. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rect` variable directly:

```
foreach (Rect r in faces)
    Cv2.Rectangle(image, (r.BottomRight.X, r.BottomRight.Y), (r.TopLeft.X, r.TopLeft.Y), 255, 1);
```

or use the `int` as this:

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < faces.Length; i++)
    Cv2.Rectangle(image, (faces[i].BottomRight.X, faces[i].BottomRight.Y), (faces[i].TopLeft.X, faces[i].TopLeft.Y), 255, 1);
```